# Updating Glue script in s3

Tags: aws-glue

I have some glue jobs with the scripts stored in s3.  When we update the scripts in the bucket, do we need to tell glue about it, or will it just pick up the changes on the next run?

For context, I'm doing this from Asure DevOps, and I'm wondering if I need to also run the `aws glue update-job` command for it to pick up the changes to the script, or if just updated the code in the bucket is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run any additional commands. Simply update the script in the bucket and the changes will be automatically picked up in the next job run.